# Why scripting languages use dynamic scope rule?

Tags: scripting, programming-languages, scope

do any one know why scripitng languages use dynamic scope rule ? I can not find any thing about this matter on the Internet.

Comment: You imply all scripting languages does this, where in fact only a few does, like Javascript and LISP and a few more.

Comment: @leppie: Javascript isn't dynamically scoped and most modern lisps aren't either (common lisp allows you to optionally make a variable dynamically scoped, but the default is static scoping - scheme and clojure don't allow dynamic scope at all).

Answer (score 12):

Scripting languages generally do *not* have [dynamic scoping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_scope#Dynamic_scoping). Scheme, Lua, Ruby, and Python are all lexically scoped. Only a few languages still around use dynamic scope because it makes it painfully hard to reason about what your code is doing by looking at it.

When you say "dynamic scoping" what are you trying to describe?

Answer (score 2):

Partly because *they can*.  Scripting languages already have substantial overhead to access variables compared to compiled languages.  Adding dynamic scoping is easy, as is adding fun features like closures.

Comment: It's funny you mention closures, because those are generally unnecessary/pointless with dynamic scoping. It should also be pointed out, that most scripting languages *don't* implement dynamic scoping (however easy it may be).

Answer (score 1):

There is a useful overview of dynamic scoping here:
From http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DynamicScoping

This includes the following:

> "Dynamic scoping is useful as a
>   substitute for globally scoped
>   variables. A function can say "let
>   current_numeric_base = 16; call other
>   functions;" and the other functions
>   will all print in hexadecimal. Then
>   when they return, and the base-setting
>   function returns, the base will return
>   to whatever it was."